# Can I post a question asking baristas their experiences?

Tags: discussion

Some baristas have an interesting story to share and there are various things that even regular customers do wrong and it drives them nuts. I don't exactly remember, but once there was a barista who once posted (not on stackexchange) about how he used to get angry at a customer who used a straw to drink his coffee. The problem with this customer was he was drinking a special type of coffee which is prepared in layers (I would be grateful if someone points out the name for me) and by using a straw he was drinking the layers in a reverse order (bottom-most first). Can I ask questions about similar experiences here?

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion, such experiences may be quite subjective. Therefore, it will be difficult to define the **correct answer**, which is against the format of the site. Thus, I opt for no.

Comment: Also, it'll turn into anecdote.stackexchange.com. not good.